# DevOps build reporting IDE0055 errors, while local build does not

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops

I'm using a few `.csproj` features:

```
<EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
<EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
```

Locally, this all works fine.

- Cause a warning, it won't build
- Format something in non-standard way, it won't build

The issue is: it builds fine locally, but Azure DevOps fails, citing IDE0055 for in-line comments on chained methods:

```
var list = new List<string>();

var cleanList = list
    // ignore zero-length strings
    .Where(l => l.Length == 0)
    // ignore too-long strings
    .Where(l => l.Length > 10)
    .ToList();
```

There are two differences:

1. Local: Windows and `MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET`
2. DevOps: Linux and `Build Engine version 17.1.1+a02f73656 for .NET`

**I'm assuming this outdated (?) build engine is to blame. Is there a way to target a different build engine?**  Hopefully it's not tied to `UseDotNet@2 packageType`, as that needed to be set to `6.0.202` so the code could run on AWS Lambda.

The full DevOps output:

```
Starting: Build projects
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.210.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet build /home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract.csproj -dl:CentralLogger,"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b/2.210.0/dotnet-build-helpers/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b/2.210.0/dotnet-build-helpers/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" -c Release -r linux-x64 -p:PublishReadyToRun=true
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.1.1+a02f73656 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract.csproj (in 367 ms).
##[error]Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/AdjustEmployeeScheduleRequest.cs(22,33): Error IDE0055: Fix formatting
/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/AdjustEmployeeScheduleRequest.cs(22,33): error IDE0055: Fix formatting [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract.csproj]
##[error]Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/AdjustEmployeeScheduleRequest.cs(23,46): Error IDE0055: Fix formatting
/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/AdjustEmployeeScheduleRequest.cs(23,46): error IDE0055: Fix formatting [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract.csproj]
##[error]Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/AdjustEmployeeScheduleRequest.cs(24,43): Error IDE0055: Fix formatting
/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/AdjustEmployeeScheduleRequest.cs(24,43): error IDE0055: Fix formatting [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract.csproj]
##[error]Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/AdjustEmployeeScheduleRequest.cs(25,43): Error IDE0055: Fix formatting
/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/AdjustEmployeeScheduleRequest.cs(25,43): error IDE0055: Fix formatting [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/AdjustEmployeeScheduleRequest.cs(22,33): error IDE0055: Fix formatting [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract.csproj]
/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/AdjustEmployeeScheduleRequest.cs(23,46): error IDE0055: Fix formatting [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract.csproj]
/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/AdjustEmployeeScheduleRequest.cs(24,43): error IDE0055: Fix formatting [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract.csproj]
/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/AdjustEmployeeScheduleRequest.cs(25,43): error IDE0055: Fix formatting [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.Contract.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    4 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.50
##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet' failed with exit code 1
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet build /home/vsts/work/1/s/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.InternalContract/Psrm.ScheduleCalculator.InternalContract.csproj -dl:CentralLogger,"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b/2.210.0/dotnet-build-helpers/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b/2.210.0/dotnet-build-helpers/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" -c Release -r linux-x64 -p:PublishReadyToRun=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, the problem looks like is related to the different OSs (Windows and Linux) where the build is running.

Since you develop and edit the C# code on your local Windows machine, it can match the consistent code style when you directly build the code on the local Windows machine.

However, when you move to the Linux machine to build, for how indentation, spaces, and new lines are aligned around .NET programming language constructs, it may be different with Windows.

For more details about the IDE0055 Error, you can reference the document "[**Formatting rule (IDE0055)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0055)".

For your case, you can try to select a Windows agent to run the build pipeline on Azure DevOps. We have provided the [Microsoft-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software) (**`windows-2022`** and **`windows-2019`**) for Azure Pipelines on Azure DevOps. Or you can set up a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) on your local Windows machine to run the build pipeline.

Comment: Well of course I'd use Windows on DevOps if I could, but we're using Linux because we're targeting Linux for our deployments.  How is it possible that an operating system could disagree on how to implement static analysis?  Isn't it all just C# binaries in the end doing the static analysis?  Shouldn't those binaries be consistent across operating systems?

Comment: Hi @Langdon, I can understand your concerns on this. However, as mentioned above, for indentation, spaces, new lines, etc.., there may be different characters between different OSs. A commonly known example is that the new line character on Windows generally is `CR+LF` while on UNIX it `LF Only`. This type of differences may cause the different results when running Code-style analysis for the same code on different OSs.

Comment: For your case, maybe you can try to disable the Code-style analysis (`<EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>false</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>`) for the code, or edit and compile the code on a Linux machine. Then move it to Azure Pipelines to see if it can work on the Linux agent.

Comment: Thanks, the line endings were precisely the problem. `.gitattributes` had forced crlf for all *.cs files.  Removing that relying on auto fixed things up.